# Google Maps resize css display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This question has been asked many times here, and that is that Google Maps display partially. My problem is: I use waypoints to trigger CSS3 animations on my page. On the page with Google Maps I have set the CSS to `display: none;` until the waypoint is hit. This causes Google Maps to break.

From my research and a search done on Stack Overflow, the fix is this (correct me if I am wrong):

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Here is my JavaScript code that I have gotten from another developer online, I have no idea where to put the Google Maps resize trigger?:

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8333406,18.6470022);
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map, 
        title:"Get Directions"
    }); 
}
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("routeStart").value;
    var end = "-33.8333406,18.6470022";
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                alert('No route could be found between the origin and destination.');
            } else if (status == 'UNKNOWN_ERROR') {
                alert('A directions request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.');
            } else if (status == 'REQUEST_DENIED') {
                alert('This webpage is not allowed to use the directions service.');
            } else if (status == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT') {
                alert('The webpage has gone over the requests limit in too short a period of time.');
            } else if (status == 'NOT_FOUND') {
                alert('At least one of the origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded.');
            } else if (status == 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
                alert('The DirectionsRequest provided was invalid.');                   
            } else {
                alert("There was an unknown error in your request. Requeststatus: \n\n"+status);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is waypoints jquery code that triggers display: block

```
// Studio Page
jQuery('.studio-page').waypoint(function() {
jQuery('.kickass-studio').addClass( 'show animated bounceInLeft' );
jQuery('.location').addClass( 'show animated bounceInRight' );
jQuery('.geo-address').addClass( 'show animated bounceInDown' );

},
{
offset: '10%'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it at the end of initialize function....
Also you need to save the map object in a variable and call the resize event again when you make the css of the google maps to display: block with this map object

Comment: Ah yes i remember reading that somewhere, how can i call it again after display: block? I actually only need to call it after display: block, but i am clueless with how to do this? I wouldnt even know where to start? I am adding my waypoints code above that triggers display: block

Comment: It will depend upon your animation ... also you need to do it when this animation ends ... if you are using any... any further code about the animation you are using will be helpful